# Nodejs installing hiredis with npm. Getting error

Tags: node.js, express, npm, hiredis

Hi im trying to install hiredis. But im getting this error:

[image]

Need advise.

Edit:After installing python im getting different error:

[image]

Comment: What could `Can't find Python executable "python"` possibly mean?

Comment: Add python to the PATH variable.

Comment: Okey. I'am doing right now.

Comment: After installing python im getting different error i added picture to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install python, which is a required piece of the build toolchain for binary modules, and hiredis is binary.

Comment: Now i installed python. But same issue. Should i restart machine?

Comment: No you just need to make sure the "python" command is properly configured in your PATH environment variable. I haven't done that on windows in years but a web search will show you the way.

Comment: `where python` from command prompt. If it's not there, try starting new command prompt if you had it open when installing Python. If still not, you'll need to add path to the list of environment variables.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same Error, and after adding the PYTHON to environment variables I got this:

> Error: Python executable "C:\Python33\python.exe" is v3.3.3, which is not supported by gyp.

I uninstalled python 3.3.3 and re-installed [Python 2.7.6.](http://www.python.org/download/) and this problem sorted out.

so I'll just emphasize it on bold here: **Install Python version beween 2.6 to 3.0 !!!**

Comment: gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v3.3.3, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! **stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.**